Converting binary data to unsigned ints
I'm getting an error pulling out binary data from a database using GORM. Here's my situation:
Database field (Aurora MySQL, if it's relevant):
    tag_to_change    binary(4)    null,

Structure:
type LogicSchemeDetail struct {
    ...
    TagToChange    uint32    `json:"tag_value"`
}

When I try to pull data out of the DB, I am getting this error:

Scan error on column index 2, name "tag_to_change": converting driver.Value type []uint8 ("\x00\x10\x00 ") to a uint32: invalid syntax

The data in the database looks like this:
0x00100010

Is there a way to tell GORM this is not an 8 byte integer besides what is indicated in the struct?

uint8 doesn't mean 8-byte-integer. It means unsigned-8-bit-value (i.e. an octet, a byte). Specifically, you have []uint8 ("\x00\x10\x00 ") which is a 4-byte array or "byte-string". You need to change your DB column type from binary(4) to int.

Thanks, I misspoke. Yes it would be possible to pull out the 4 bytes in the database into an array of 8-bit uints. However, I am asking for a uint32 variable, and somehow getting an []uint8 array. Perhaps I should change the struct definition as opposed to changing the DB field? The data with which I am working is in 4 byte format, so I'd like to avoid making a DB change. Thx.
